# Javascript sort nested array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, ecmascript-6

I need to return the same array,
same structure,

I need to loop inside each array object and reorder the planningDiagnosi.

I need to have tha array content sorted by outcomeStatusId from the lowest to the hightest number.

It looks a simple task, I did many tryes but I couldn't find any solution.

Like this:

```
var myArray = [
  {
    "objectName":"ROME",
    "planningProcess": [
      {
        "objectName":"MOSCA",
        "workflowProcessId": 1066,
        "planningDiagnosis": [
          {
            "objectName":"NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 3,
            "planningInterventions": [
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName":"NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 1,
            "planningInterventions": [
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName":"NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 2,
            "planningInterventions": [
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          }
        ],
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    "objectName":"ROME",
    "planningProcess": [
      {
        "objectName":"MOSCA",
        "workflowProcessId": 1066,
        "planningDiagnosis": [
          {
            "objectName":"NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 3,
            "planningInterventions": [
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName":"NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 1,
            "planningInterventions": [
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName":"NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 2,
            "planningInterventions": [
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          }
        ],
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    "objectName":"ROME",
    "planningProcess": [
      {
        "objectName":"MOSCA",
        "workflowProcessId": 1066,
        "planningDiagnosis": [
          {
            "objectName":"NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 1,
            "planningInterventions": [
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName":"NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 1,
            "planningInterventions": [
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName":"NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 1,
            "planningInterventions": [
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          }
        ],
      },

    ]
  }
  ]
```

// MY SOLUTION BUT NOT WORING

```
 const f = myArray.map(p=>{
      p.planningProcess.map(pr=>{
        return pr.planningDiagnosis.sort((a,b)=>a.outcomeStatusId - b.outcomeStatusId)
      })
      return p;
    });
    console.log(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix your problem?

Sort the array

```
pr.planningDiagnosis.sort((a, b) => a.outcomeStatusId - b.outcomeStatusId)
```

Then return the sorted array.

```js
var myArray = [{
    "objectName": "ROME",
    "planningProcess": [{
        "objectName": "MOSCA",
        "workflowProcessId": 1066,
        "planningDiagnosis": [{
            "objectName": "NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 3,
            "planningInterventions": [{
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName": "NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 1,
            "planningInterventions": [{
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName": "NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 2,
            "planningInterventions": [{
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          }
        ],
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    "objectName": "ROME",
    "planningProcess": [{
        "objectName": "MOSCA",
        "workflowProcessId": 1066,
        "planningDiagnosis": [{
            "objectName": "NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 3,
            "planningInterventions": [{
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName": "NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 1,
            "planningInterventions": [{
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName": "NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 2,
            "planningInterventions": [{
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          }
        ],
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    "objectName": "ROME",
    "planningProcess": [{
        "objectName": "MOSCA",
        "workflowProcessId": 1066,
        "planningDiagnosis": [{
            "objectName": "NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 1,
            "planningInterventions": [{
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName": "NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 1,
            "planningInterventions": [{
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          },
          {
            "objectName": "NEWYORK",
            "outcomeStatusId": 1,
            "planningInterventions": [{
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              },
              {
                "name": "rivalutare rischio lesioni ri-compilando Braden a 7 g",
              }
            ],

          }
        ],
      },

    ]
  }
]

myArray.forEach(p => {
  p.planningProcess.forEach(pr => {
    // below line will sort in place and need not return anything
    pr.planningDiagnosis.sort((a, b) => a.outcomeStatusId - b.outcomeStatusId)
  })
});
console.log(myArray)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks, now its more clear.